# How to escape a character in vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

How do I escape a character in vba? I am trying to escape a `;` since I have a string that the compiler cuts at `;`. 

 I tried the `\` but it doesn't seem to work. Any other special escape in `vba`?

```
Set mySqlCon = wrkODBC.OpenConnection("connection1", , , "DRIVER={MYSQL ODBC 5.1 DRIVER};" _
   & "SERVER=testserver.com;port=3306;" _
   & "DATABASE=test;" _
   & "USER={coding;Enthusiast};" _ 
   & "Password=pwd;")
```

Comment: Can you show the troublesome string?  So long as the ; is in quotes it should be okay.  VBA does have an escape code as they are not required.

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem adding a semicolon to a VB string literal. Post some code and perhaps the issue might be more evident.

Comment: I don't think `;` would be a special character. Why do you think VBA cuts the string at it?

Comment: @DavidW the problem is that, at every semi-colon, that string is being concatened i think

Comment: Where, exactly, is it breaking?

Comment: There is no problem with what you're showing. What is the exact error you're encountering.

Comment: @OP is this the same as your other post about the curly braces and the semi-colon in `{coding;Enthusiast}`?

Comment: nope. the other one was about curly braces...

Comment: It looks like another syntax error in your string. Use of semi-colon ";" in VBA string should be OK. Best regards,

Comment: Is the failure tied, somehow, to the specification of the user parameter in the connection string? Without more information regarding the specific error you're encountering, a complete resolution is nearly impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine your string-building piece in the Immediate window:

```vb
? "DRIVER={MYSQL ODBC 5.1 DRIVER;}" _
   & "SERVER=testserver.com;port=3306;" _
   & "DATABASE=test;" _
   & "USER={coding;Enthusiast};" _
   & "Password=pwd;"
DRIVER={MYSQL ODBC 5.1 DRIVER;}SERVER=testserver.com;port=3306;DATABASE=test;USER={coding;Enthusiast};Password=pwd;
```

It produced a valid VBA string for me using Access 2010.

If the issue is that ODBC does not like that connection string, move the first semicolon outside the `}` bracket:

```vb
? "DRIVER={MYSQL ODBC 5.1 DRIVER};" _
   & "SERVER=testserver.com;port=3306;" _
   & "DATABASE=test;" _
   & "USER={coding;Enthusiast};" _
   & "Password=pwd;"
DRIVER={MYSQL ODBC 5.1 DRIVER};SERVER=testserver.com;port=3306;DATABASE=test;USER={coding;Enthusiast};Password=pwd;
```

If you're still having a problem with a semicolon inside your string, try adding it based on its ASCII value instead of as a literal `;` character:

```vb
? "a" & Chr(59) & "b"
a;b
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about a semicolon in VBA, and thus requires no special escaping or other treatment. The following snippet echoes your post and works just fine:

```
Sub foo()
  Dim a As String
  a = "foo" _
     & "; bar"

     MsgBox a

End Sub
```